# how can i do loop and display the albums data?

Tags: reactjs

How can I loop though this array of objects and display their data on my React app?

It represents a list of singers and a nested list with their albums.

Need help to iterate over each artist and then over their albums, displaying all necessary information.

I want to be able to have all data displayed on screen using react components.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jimi Hendrix",
    "cover": "jimi_hendrix",
    "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "albums": [
      {
        "albumId": "a1",
        "title": "Electric Ladyland",
        "year": 1968,
        "cover": "electric-ladyland",
        "price": 20
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a2",
        "title": "Experience",
        "year": 1971,
        "cover": "experienced",
        "price": 25
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a3",
        "title": "Isle of Wright",
        "year": 1971,
        "cover": "isle_of_wright",
        "price": 15
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a4",
        "title": "Band of Gypsys",
        "year": 1970,
        "cover": "band_of_gypsys",
        "price": 10
      }
    ],
    "genre": "rock, blues"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Madonna",
    "cover": "madonna",
    "bio": "Lorem ipsum",
    "albums": [
      {
        "albumId": "b1",
        "title": "Like a Virgin",
        "year": 1984,
        "cover": "like_a_virgin",
        "price": 20
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b2",
        "title": "True Blue",
        "year": 1986,
        "cover": "true_blue",
        "price": 25
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b3",
        "title": "Erotica",
        "year": 1994,
        "cover": "erotica",
        "price": 15
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b4",
        "title": "Ray of Light",
        "year": 1998,
        "cover": "ray_of_light",
        "price": 10
      }
    ],
    "genre": "pop"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete example on how to loop your list and render your components correctly! [**See it live!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-pw041)

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jimi Hendrix",
    "cover": "jimi_hendrix",
    "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "albums": [
      {
        "albumId": "a1",
        "title": "Electric Ladyland",
        "year": 1968,
        "cover": "electric-ladyland",
        "price": 20
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a2",
        "title": "Experience",
        "year": 1971,
        "cover": "experienced",
        "price": 25
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a3",
        "title": "Isle of Wright",
        "year": 1971,
        "cover": "isle_of_wright",
        "price": 15
      },
      {
        "albumId": "a4",
        "title": "Band of Gypsys",
        "year": 1970,
        "cover": "band_of_gypsys",
        "price": 10
      }
    ],
    "genre": "rock, blues"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Madonna",
    "cover": "madonna",
    "bio": "Lorem ipsum",
    "albums": [
      {
        "albumId": "b1",
        "title": "Like a Virgin",
        "year": 1984,
        "cover": "like_a_virgin",
        "price": 20
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b2",
        "title": "True Blue",
        "year": 1986,
        "cover": "true_blue",
        "price": 25
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b3",
        "title": "Erotica",
        "year": 1994,
        "cover": "erotica",
        "price": 15
      },
      {
        "albumId": "b4",
        "title": "Ray of Light",
        "year": 1998,
        "cover": "ray_of_light",
        "price": 10
      }
    ],
    "genre": "pop"
  }
]



const List = ({singers}) => (
  <ul>
    
    {
      singers.map((singer, i) => {
        return <Singer key={i} singer={singer} />
      })
    }
  </ul>
)

const Singer = ({singer}) => (
  <li>
    <p>Name: {singer.name}</p>
    <p>Cover: {singer.cover}</p>
    <p>Bio: {singer.bio}</p>
    <p>Genre: {singer.genre}</p>
    <ul>
      {
        singer.albums.map((album, i) => {
          return <Album key={i} album={album} />
        })
      }
    </ul>
  </li>
)

const Album = ({album}) => (
  <li>
    <p>Title: {album.title}</p>
    <p>Year: {album.year}</p>
    <p>Cover: {album.cover}</p>
    <p>Price: {album.price}</p>
  </li>
)

ReactDOM.render(<List singers={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  {[ { "id": 1, "name": "Jimi Hendrix", "cover": "jimi_hendrix", "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.", "albums": [ { "albumId": "a1", "title": "Electric Ladyland", "year": 1968, "cover": "electric-ladyland", "price": 20 }, { "albumId": "a2", "title": "Experience", "year": 1971, "cover": "experienced", "price": 25 }, { "albumId": "a3", "title": "Isle of Wright", "year": 1971, "cover": "isle_of_wright", "price": 15 }, { "albumId": "a4", "title": "Band of Gypsys", "year": 1970, "cover": "band_of_gypsys", "price": 10 } ], "genre": "rock, blues" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Madonna", "cover": "madonna", "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.", "albums": [ { "albumId": "b1", "title": "Like a Virgin", "year": 1984, "cover": "like_a_virgin", "price": 20 }, { "albumId": "b2", "title": "True Blue", "year": 1986, "cover": "true_blue", "price": 25 }, { "albumId": "b3", "title": "Erotica", "year": 1994, "cover": "erotica", "price": 15 }, { "albumId": "b4", "title": "Ray of Light", "year": 1998, "cover": "ray_of_light", "price": 10 } ], "genre": "pop" } ].map((album) => (
    <div button key={album.albumId}>
      <p>{album.title}</p>
      <p>{album.price}</p>
    </div>
  ))}
```